# How to setup database on tomcat start

Tags: servlets, deployment

I'm writing a simple app using pure Servlet API, no frameworks. The app uses HSQLDB at predefined location inside user's folder. I need to create table structure from inside application on first start or during deployment.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+an+Oracle+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat ,these link will help you?

Comment: @YeWin no, actually I already have fully functioning application. I just want to automate deployment process. Basically I need a way to execute a SQL script during deployment or first start.

Comment: oh i see, you don't want to use Spring too??

Comment: Since application is ready, it's too late to use Spring :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of research I came to solution that uses ServletContextListener. I'll skip explanation and show you the code.

```
@WebListener
public class DatabaseCreator implements ServletContextListener {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Resource(
            name = "jdbc/rssDS",
            type = javax.sql.DataSource.class,
            authenticationType = Resource.AuthenticationType.CONTAINER
    )
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            logger.error("Data source wasn't initialized");
        }
        String sql = readStreamToString(sce.getServletContext());
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(sql)) {
            logger.error("SQL script is empty");
        }
        try {
            logger.debug("Executing SQL script");
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to create database table structure", e);
        }
    }

    private String readStreamToString(ServletContext ctx) {
        //skipped, reads stream contents into String
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
}
```